# Running a ruby script globally

Tags: ruby, command-line, global

I'm writing a command line application in ruby and want to run it globally in my shell, without having to preface my call with `./` or with `ruby <filepath>` - just as I would run `git`, `brew` or `rails`.

The structure of my simple application is as follows: I've got a directory in `/Developer` folder called `rubyPlug`. Inside *rubyPlug* is *plug* and *Formulae.rb*.

I'm writing a command line application in ruby and want to run it globally in my shell, without having to preface my call with `./` or with `ruby <filepath>` - just as I would run `git`, `brew` or `rails`.

The structure of my simple application is as follows: I've got a directory in `/Developer` called `rubyPlug`. Inside `rubyPlug` is `plug` and `Formulae.rb`. `Formulae.rb` is where all the application specific code is stored. `Plug` stores some boilerplate startup code:

````
!/usr/bin/env ruby 
require  "/Users/theideasmith/Developer/rubyPlug/Formulae.rb"
 begin
   x = Application.new ARGV
 rescue Errno::ENOENT => err
   abort "plug: #{err.message}"
 end```
````

**I want to run my app by typing `plug <args>`. If I'm storing `plug` globally, how would I structure my `require()` call?**

I've included `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` in `plug`, ran `chmod +x plug`, and tried `sudo cp plug /usr/bin/plug.` My script ran, but failed at the `require "/Users/.../Formulae.rb"` call. How do I avoid this - do I have to store the parent directory as some sort of package in `/usr/bin`? I've included `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` in `plug`, ran `chmod +x plug`, and tried `sudo cp plug /usr/local/bin/plug`. I was then able to type `plug <args>`, but I then got an error message related to my `require` call not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are there no leading slashes for your paths? Is this a Mac OS thing?

Answer (score 0):

`require` should work if you use an absolute path i.e. one that starts with `/`. You can also use `Dir.chdir` to make the script run as though it is not in `/usr/bin`.

Also you should really put it in `/usr/local/bin`. That's the proper place for custom executables.